# Fetch Redis key/value pairs in parallel

Tags: redis, lua, redis-scan

I need to fetch all key/value pairs that match a certain key prefix. This needs to be done in parallel (eg. using threads).

My idea is to scan over all keys matching a prefix and filter only those whose `(hash(key) % partition_size) == partition_id`, where `partition_size` is the number of parallel processes and `partition_id` is a number between `0..partition_size-1` which is assigned to each process.

What does Redis command or script look like? Is there a non-script way of doing so?

Comment: It is not clear, what is your goal for "fetch all key/value pairs in parallel". I may assume, that you actually want to investigate the fetched values further and need the "fetch in parallel" for speed. With this assumption I'd suggest you consider an approach, to scan Redis-entries server-side, filtering the data by value on server with a special Lua-script, returning to the client only needed data. I created a demo-repo for that approach: https://github.com/a-bobkov/redis-search-values-demo

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the search capability of Redis Stack for this.  You would use the `FT.CREATE` command to create a search index over part of the keyspace containing either Redis Hashes or Redis Stack JSON documents, then use the `FT.SEARCH` command to search for matches with a more SQL like syntax.

This would allow you do to things like this (demo with hashes, you could also use JSON):

Create some data:

```
> hset data:1 value 1 data hello
(integer) 2

> hset data:2 value 2 data world
(integer) 2

> hset data:3 value 3 data how
(integer) 2

> hset data:4 value 4 data are
(integer) 2

> hset data:5 value 5 data you
(integer) 2
```

Create an index over the data, here I'm indexing `value` as a number but you could also index `data` as a tag or full-text.

```
> ft.create idx:data on hash prefix 1 data: schema value numeric sortable
"OK"
```

Search will now keep track of all changes to keys with prefix `data:` whose type is Hash.

Now, I can do some searches and get data back.  Everything where value is less then 3:

```
> ft.search idx:data "@value:[-inf 2]"
1) "2"
2) "data:1"
3) 1) "value"
   2) "1"
   3) "data"
   4) "hello"
4) "data:2"
5) 1) "value"
   2) "2"
   3) "data"
   4) "world"
```

Search that returns all indexed items:

```
> ft.search idx:data "*"
1) "5"
2) "data:1"
3) 1) "value"
   2) "1"
   3) "data"
   4) "hello"
4) "data:4"
5) 1) "value"
   2) "4"
   3) "data"
   4) "are"
6) "data:3"
7) 1) "value"
   2) "3"
   3) "data"
   4) "how"
8) "data:2"
9) 1) "value"
   2) "2"
   3) "data"
   4) "world"
10) "data:5"
11) 1) "value"
   2) "5"
   3) "data"
   4) "you"
```

By default you'll get the first 10 and can paginate using `LIMIT`... let's get 2:

```
> ft.search idx:data "*" LIMIT 0 2
1) "5"
2) "data:1"
3) 1) "value"
   2) "1"
   3) "data"
   4) "hello"
4) "data:4"
5) 1) "value"
   2) "4"
   3) "data"
   4) "are"
```

If you only want certain parts of the data back use `RETURN`:

```
> ft.search idx:data "*" LIMIT 0 2 RETURN 1 data
1) "5"
2) "data:1"
3) 1) "data"
   2) "hello"
4) "data:4"
5) 1) "data"
   2) "are"
```

If you just want the keynames, use `NOCONTENT`:

```
> ft.search idx:data "*" LIMIT 0 2 NOCONTENT
1) "5"
2) "data:1"
3) "data:4"
```

Note that Redis is fundamentally single threaded so "in parallel" will have limited use here.

References:

- Redis Stack: https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/install-stack/
- FT.CREATE: https://redis.io/commands/ft.create/
- FT.SEARCH: https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/
- Course on search with Redis: https://university.redis.com/courses/ru203/
- Course on search with JSON documents and Redis: https://university.redis.com/courses/ru204/